# Enable button after upload file doesn't work first time

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, file-upload

I am trying to set the enabled state of my button to be enabled after a file is selected to upload

The problem is i have to select the file twice before the button is enabled

```
   <form name="importForm">
    <div ng-if="vm.results == null">

        <div>
            <label>File*</label>

            <input id = "uploadFile" ng-model="vm.fileImporter.file"
                   onchange="angular.element(this).scope().file_changed(this)"
                   required
                   type="file" accept="*" />
        </div>

        <div class="footer">
            <button ng-disabled="importForm.$invalid" ng-click="vm.importFile()">Import</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>


    $scope.file_changed = function (element) {
        $scope.$apply(function (scope) {
            var file = element.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            reader.onload = function (evt) {
                vm.fileImporter.file = evt.target.result;
            }
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
onchange="angular.element(this).scope().file_changed(this)"
```

By doing this, you are working on the input scope, and not your controller scope (and thus, you are not referring to your function `$scope.file_changed` ).

Try changing your line to something like this (notice the using of ng-change instead of onchange):

```
ng-change="file_changed(this)"
```

It should solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Luxor001, when i do this i get an error  file_changed is not defined do i need to change the signature of the method in the vm?

Comment: my bad, you should use ng-change instead of onchange, i didn't noticed that. ng-change is an angular directive (and you should use it), onchange is pure javascript (wich is bad: what's the point of using angular then?) see my edited answer for details

Comment: try initializing your vm.fileImporter.file in your controller. then, ng-change should work. If it will not, i don't know honestly what to do: try to make a plunker of the issue and post it.